# Arduino how can i edit static unsigned short?

Tags: c++, arduino

My question is how i can edit an static unsigned short. I'm completly new in Arduino coding and I have no clue how to solve this.

And sorry for my English. :)

So I have in my Code following static unsigned short:
`static unsigned short code[NUMBER_OF_KEYS][4] = { {634, 123, 124, 234},{111, 222, 333, 444} };`

I now want to add a block so that the variable would look something like this: 
`static unsigned short code[NUMBER_OF_KEYS][4] = { {634, 123, 124, 234},{111, 222, 333, 444},{235, 213, 461, 192} };`

And i want to delete a whole block by the numbers. So that i have the numbers in this block and i want to delete the block where the nubers are the same.

Answer (score 1):

As i can understand you want to add to
`static unsigned short code[NUMBER_OF_KEYS][4] = { {634, 123, 124, 234},{111, 222, 333, 444} };`
values
`{235, 213, 461, 192}`.

First interpretation of your question is to do it offline, before your program is compiled and run on Arduino board.

You simply have to modify `static unsigned short code[NUMBER_OF_KEYS][4] = { {634, 123, 124, 234},{111, 222, 333, 444} };` by adding bolded parts `static unsigned short code[NUMBER_OF_KEYS`**`+1`**`][4] = { {634, 123, 124, 234},{111, 222, 333, 444}` **`,{235, 213, 461, 192}`**`,};` Increasing NUMBER_OF_KEYS can be done in `#define NUMBER_OF_KEYS VALUE` section. Simply increase VALUE. Define sections are often on the top of source files.

**Second solution to modify it while program is running**: you are using **static allocation of memory**. It's not connected to `static unsigned char` type, but to what is after `=` sign. You're telling compilator to allocate only memory for `sizeof(char)*NUMBER_OF_KEYS*4` bytes. `sizeof(short)` equals 16 bites or equally 2 bytes. Simplifying it's `8*NUMBER_OF_KEYS` bytes.

You asked how to add new section to the variable. So you will need `4*sizeof(short)*1` more bytes of memory.

My suggestion is to declare it as **not static** variable type, then **use dynamic allocation of memory** to 2-dimmentional pointer. If necessary you will be as program runs allocate more memory for more sections of values, copy from source to newly allocated memory and at the and ad the end (or somewhere else) new values.  Don't forget to free not used memory, then assign value of pointer to your variable. After all of that you will be able to add it as program runs.

Answer (score 1):

`static unsigned short code[NUMBER_OF_KEYS][4]` declaration would reserve fixed size of memory for that data.

So by declaring `[NUMBER_OF_KEYS]`, you could operate only with a limit of `NUMBER_OF_KEYS`.

Very simple solution is to reserve space for **MAX** possible number of elements and trace the number of actual number of keys in array.
For example

```
constexpr int MAX_NUMBER_OF_KEYS = 10;
static unsigned short code[MAX_NUMBER_OF_KEYS][4];
int keysCount = 0;

// add keys: code[0] = {634, 123, 124, 234}
code[0][0] = 634; code[0][1] = 123; code[0][2] = 124; code[0][3] = 234;
keysCount = 1;

// remove keys from position 0
code[0][0] = 0; code[0][1] = 0; code[0][2] = 0; code[0][3] = 0;
keysCount = 0;
```

So you place any sort of key codes at any position and trace count of actual number so not to access rubbish data. That's also need to handle removing gaps. So if you have code[0], code[1], code[2] and removing code[1], you probably want to move code[2] in position of code[1].

Better solution is to use C++ with support of dynamic memory.
Commonly `std::vector` is used for that purpose.

```
// For individual Keys codes 
// so each KeysCode is entries {634, 123, 124, 234} or {111, 222, 333, 444}, etc
using KeysCode = std::array<unsigned short, 4>;

// Init
// 'code' would have 2 elements of respective KeysCode
std::vector<KeysCode> code = {{634, 123, 124, 234}, {111, 222, 333, 444}};

// add third element {235, 213, 461, 192} in the end
code.push_back(KeysCode{235, 213, 461, 192});

// erase code[1] by index, eg {111, 222, 333, 444}
code.erase(code.begin() + 1);

// find {634, 123, 124, 234} and erase it
auto removeIt = std::remove(code.begin(), code.end(), KeysCode{634, 123, 124, 234});
code.erase(removeIt, code.end());
```

Comment: The static has a bit different meaning in global scope and in functions. In global scope it means "this function or variable will not be visible from other compilation units" (therefore no naming collisions if it's in header, but each compilation unit has it's own instance, and you'll get warning if it's unused).

Used in function it means localy visible "global" variable. It gets instantiated in the first run (if you don't use initializer, it's initialized to default value - same as all global variables), and it survives out of function scope

Comment: Right, sorry bad wording. I've fixed that part a bit